# Did אָכִיש actually use Hashem?

Tags: tanach, shemos-sacred-names, nedarim-shevuot, samuel-shmuel-book-of

> וַיִּקְרָ֨א אָכִ֜ישׁ אֶל־דָּוִ֗ד וַיֹּ֣אמֶר אֵ֠לָיו חַי־יְהוָ֞ה כִּי־יָשָׁ֣ר אַתָּ֗ה
> ([שמואל א 29:6](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.29.6?lang=bi))

This has the פְּלִשְׁתִּי swearing by Hashem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question!

According to [Radak](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Samuel.29.6?lang=bi&p2=Radak_on_I_Samuel.29.6.1&lang2=bi) on the verse, Achish wanted to convince David that he was only letting him go because of peer pressure from the other seranim (leaders of the Phillistines), and not because he no longer trusted him, so he took a vow before him in the name of David's God to show his faith in him (David).

This understanding is also brought in Yalkut Me'am Loez on the verse.

Edit: Another thought that comes to mind is that Achish was very likely around back when the Ark was wreaking havoc among the Phillistine cities. He might not yet have been king of Gat, but he was most likely aware of the might of Hashem, and so, though he did not worship Him, his taking a vow in His name may have included a facet of fear/awe of Hashem and not just merely as a sign to David.